# Excel 2010 - VBA code to Write Formatted Numbers to CSV

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm working on a 5 sheet workbook, where a button named `ExportCSV` on sheet 5 exports data on sheet 3. More specifically, the button runs a VBA code that goes row by row and checks the first 3 cells for data. If any of the first three cells have data, then the whole row is selected. After all rows with data are selected, the data is written row by row to a CSV file (the file itself is semicolon-delimited, however).

The problem that I'm having is that some cell formatting is being copied over, but some is not. For example, values in cells formatted for Accounting with a $ are formatted correctly, meaning "$12,345,678.90" shows up as "$12,345,678.90." However, values in cells formatted as Accounting but without $ are not being written to the csv correctly, meaning "12,345,678.90" is being written as "12345678.9."

Below is the Macro in question.

```
Dim planSheet As Worksheet
Dim temSheet As Worksheet

Private Sub ExportCSV_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim lColumn As Long
    Dim intResult As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    On Error GoTo Errhandler
    Set temSheet = Worksheets(3)
    i = 2
    Do While i < 1001
        j = 1
        Do While j < 4
            If Not IsEmpty(temSheet.Cells(i, j)) Then
                temSheet.Select
                lColumn = temSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                temSheet.Range(temSheet.Cells(2, 1), temSheet.Cells(i, lColumn)).Select
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).InitialFileName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Title = "Select a Path"
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).ButtonName = "Select Path"
    intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show

    If intResult <> 0 Then
        'dispaly message box
        strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    Dim X As Long, FF As Long, S() As String
    ReDim S(1 To Selection.Rows.Count)
    For X = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
        S(X) = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Selection.Rows(X).Value)), ";")
    Next
    FF = FreeFile
    FilePath = strPath & "\Data" & Format(Now(), "yyyyMMddhhmmss") & ".csv"
    Open FilePath For Output As #FF
    Print #FF, Join(S, vbNewLine)
    Close #FF

    Errhandler:
        ...Error Handling Code omitted

End Sub
```

I need to be able to copy over the exact formatting of the cells. Converting the no-$ cells to $ cells won't work because the values without $ are being used for a calculation later on in the process that can handle the commas, but not a $, and I can't change the code for the later calculation (proprietary plug-in doing the calculation.) Also, the rows have mixed content, meaning some values in the row are text instead of numbers.

Comment: You're going to need to considerably overhaul the `For x = 1 to Selection.Rows.Count` loop. You will have to do cell-by-cell iteration over an array of values from each row's range, and update the array to include the *formatted* values (by default it would use the `.Value` which is entirely ignorant of any formatting).  Does that make sense?  If so, give it a shot and we can try to help if you get stuck.

Comment: That does make some sense. I guess I was just seeing if anyone had any idea to do not have to do that.

Comment: Right, I don't think there's another way when you're dealing with *conditionally* changing the values that need to be written to  what you're doing right now is an implicit conversion from the entire selection's row ranges, to an array, and then you're using the `Join` function to coerce that array in to a string, so that it can be written to the FSO file. The implicit conversion there will use the `.Value` of each cell in the row.  Instead, you need to build the array from the cell's `.Text` property which can only be done one cell/value at a time I think.

Comment: @DavidZemens Overhaul was right. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following David Zemens' advice and overhauled the section that was `For X = 1 to Selection.Rows.Count` See below.

```
For X = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
    For Y = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count
        If Y <> Selection.Columns.Count Then
            If IsNumeric(temSheet.Cells(X + 1, Y).Value) Then
                If temSheet.Cells(X + 1, Y).Value = 0 Then
                    S(X) = S(X) & ";"
                Else
                    S(X) = S(X) & Replace(temSheet.Cells(X + 1, Y).Text, " ", "") & ";"
                End If
            Else
                S(X) = S(X) & Trim(temSheet.Cells(X + 1, Y).Text) & ";"
            End If
        Else
            If IsNumeric(temSheet.Cells(X + 1, Y).Value) Then
                If temSheet.Cells(X + 1, Y).Value <> 0 Then
                    S(X) = S(X) & Replace(temSheet.Cells(X + 1, Y).Text, " ", "")
                End If
            Else
                S(X) = S(X) & Trim(temSheet.Cells(X + 1, Y).Text)
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Some more formatting was necessary. It goes cell by cell, purposefully skipping the first row of the sheet. The `.Text` property of some of the cells returned empty space before the value or between the $ and value, so it had to be removed. `Trim` removes leading and ending spaces while `Replace` replaces all spaces in the export.

Comment: Well-done.  If performance is an issue you could *first* put the entire row/range `.Value` into an array, and then iterate that rather than doing cell-by-cell iteration. It will probably be faster, but may not be noticeable on small datasets.  If you have many thousands of rows I might do it that way though.

Comment: Usually datasets aren't that large, but I ran a test with about 2000 in total. The selection took about 5-10 seconds. The export was instant. So performance shouldn't be an issue. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Right the export should be super efficient you're using the optimized I/O functions to print the entire file at once. it's only the cell iteration that takes some time, but 5-10 seconds is tolerable for most people, so I wouldn't fuss with it unless it becomes a problem in the future :)  Cheers.